# Long running workflow with conditional transition

Tags: persistence, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I have long-running workflow service, based on state machine, that at some point has to compare two values and if they are equal it should transition to a new state.

However, once I introduce trigerless transition with compare, workflow instance never goes to idle.

What is the best approach to do this, to have conditional transition that is evaluated once per entering source state, and goes back idle if condition is false.

Comment: You can create a bookmark CompareTwoValues in a state. Evaluate the result and transit to new state if equal, otherwise stay at the same state

Comment: That is not going to work as it will reevaluate the condition endlessly. On each returning the state, trigger will be revaluated.

Comment: If you create a bookmark and the workflow instance executes the bookmark activity, it will be kept in idle state until the bookmark is resumed.